# how to cancel filtering if two string conditions occur

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have code that looks like this

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=100000)
def get_time(event_1, event_2):
    clean = df[(df['event_name'] == event_1) | (df['event_name'] == event_2)]
    ...
final_df = get_time(event_1 = 'open', event_2 = 'close')
```

So what I want to do is to have my original data without filtering if event_1 = 'open', event_2 = 'close'. In the other cases I want it to filter like in line with clean variable
Original output

| date | event |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/10/05 | open |
| 2022/10/06 | jump |
| 2022/10/05 | run |
| 2022/10/06 | close |

Expected when event_1 = 'open', event_2 = 'close'

| date | event |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/10/05 | open |
| 2022/10/06 | jump |
| 2022/10/05 | run |
| 2022/10/06 | close |

Expected when event_1 = 'open', event_2 = 'jump'

| date | event |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/10/05 | open |
| 2022/10/06 | jump |

Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you provide a larger example when there are multiple open and close events, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `if` statement

```
def get_time(event_1, event_2):
    if event_1 == 'open' and event_2 == 'close':
        clean = df
    else:
        clean = df[(df['event_name'] == event_1) | (df['event_name'] == event_2)]
    ...
```